# How to store data in an image with php?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

I have tried to use the imagick library to create two functions like this:

```
function storeCoordinatesImage($img_path, $coordinates){
    $im = new imagick($img_path);
    $im->setImageProperty("coords", $coordinates);
    $im->writeImage($img_path);
}

function getCoordinatesImage($img_path){
    $im = new imagick($img_path);
    return $im->getImageProperty("coords");
}
```

If I run:

```
if(!storeCoordinatesImage("I.jpg", "hi")) echo "fal";
echo getCoordinatesImage("I.jpg");
```

Nothing is returned.

But if I run:

```
$im = new imagick($img_path);
$im->setImageProperty("coords", "hello");
echo $im->getImageProperty("coords");
```

it returns "hello".

So it must be some issue with writing to the image? Although none of these functions are returning `false`. (i.e they are all working)

Comment: `ImageProperties` are "public" key/value attributes associated with ImageMagick's image stack (or list of images in memory). They are not to be confused with meta-data, or file-header attributes. Any values populated _can_ influence delegate-format encoding, but will be deleted at time of stack deallocation.

Comment: @emcconville so what is a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ben mentioned this is not possible. Instead you can add a "comment":

```
function storeCommentImage($img_path, $coordinates){
    $im = new imagick($img_path);
    $im->commentImage($coordinates);
    return $im->writeImage($img_path);
}

function getCommentImage($img_path){
    $im = new imagick($img_path);
    return $im->getImageProperty("comment");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an image's profile payload to store arbitrary data. Although a JSON payload stored in an image comment (i.e. `JPG_COM`) tag seems the quick-n-easy, several competing technologies exist for this propose. The most popular being [exif](/questions/tagged/exif), but I would recommend [xmp](/questions/tagged/xmp).

### eXtensible Metadata Platform

In my opinion, `xmp` seems over engineered, but does offer a platform to ensure all vendor proprietary information is separated via XML namespace.

Wikipedia has a [great overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform), and Adobe's white papers ([pdf](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMP%20SDK%20Release%20cc-2016-08/XMPSpecificationPart1.pdf)) do a great job outlining the "does-n-don'ts" for a vendor to implement.

ImageMagick doesn't handle anything outside of read/write profile payloads, so you would be responsible for implementing a XML manager.

For example...

```php
// A minimal XMP tempalte
$XMP_BASE='<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMPTk 2.8">'
         .'<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"></rdf:RDF>'
         .'</x:xmpmeta>';

$xmp = new DOMDocument();
$xmp->loadXML($XMP_BASE);
// Create a <rdf:Descriptiom> & <Coords> DOM element.
foreach($xmp->getElementsByTagName('RDF') as $node) {
    $coords = $xmp->createElement('Coords', 'hello');
    $description = $xmp->createElement('rdf:Description');
    $description->setAttribute('about', '');
    $description->appendChild($coords);
    $node->appendChild($description);
}

$img = new Imagick('rose:');
// Write profile to image.
$img->setImageProfile('xmp', $xmp->saveXML());
$img->writeImage('output.jpg');
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$img2 = new Imagick('output.jpg');
$xmp2 = new DOMDocument();
// Read profile from image.
$xmp2->loadXML($img2->getImageProfile('xmp'));
// Grab `Coords' value
foreach($xmp2->getElementsByTagName('Coords') as $coords) {
    print $coords->textContent . PHP_EOL;
}
//=> "hello"
```

And you can verify with the `identify` utility.

```
identify -verbose output.jpg | grep Coords
#=> Coords: hello
```

Of course, you would also need to implement a XML DOM "merge" method in the event that an image already contains a XMP profile, and you don't wish to overwrite existing data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can't persist that data for jpegs: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/55#issuecomment-157114261

Maybe try with a png?